# Mean of selected values

Tags: r, median

I want to take the mean of some columns to form one columns as follows:

```
ffc1$IPC <- rowMeans(ffc1[,c("m5c6j","m5c6g","m5c6c","m5c6h", "m5c6i", "m5c6l", "m5c6m", "m5c6n", "m5c7", "m5d20g", "m5d20j", "m5d20h", "m5d20i", "m5d20l", "m5d20m", "m5d20n", "m5d21", "m5d20c")], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Next I check unique values: `unique(ffc1$IPC)` which yields the following:

```
-3, -2, 1, 4, 3, 3, -1, NA
```

Then I want to impute the missing values (NA) above with the median of only the positive values in my column. How do I tweak the following code to get the desired output?

```
#Impute
ffc1$IPC[is.na(ffc1$IPC)] <- median(ffc1$IPC, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may do

```
ffc1$IPC[is.na(ffc1$IPC)] <-median(ffc1$IPC[ffc1$IPC > 0], na.rm = TRUE)
```